# Unable to access Javascript outside Rails aplication

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, asset-pipeline, digital-ocean

We have a JS file which is accessed by different applications.

These applications able to access the JS from our staging application deployed Heroku(e.g, https://xyx.herokuapp.com/assets/businesses/affiliate/affiliate.js) but are not able access file(e.g., https://ourlivesite.com/assets/businesses/affiliate/advowire_affiliate.js from Production deployed on Digital Ocean.

It seem related to asset precompile but could not figureout the issue.

Can anybody help us to identify what could be the problem?

Comment: In production, Rails doesn't serve individual JS files. It combines them into manifest files (application.js and others specified in config.assets.precompile) and serves the manifest files. You can add the js file to *config.assets.precompile* in *production.rb* to make it accessible by different application, but I am not sure if that's the right way to do it.

Comment: From the guide `In production, Rails inserts an MD5 fingerprint into each filename so that the file is cached by the web browser.` So each time I deploy the application, name of the file would change and that won't work in our scenario as we have to distribute this file to many site owners. We cannot ask owners to change file name each time we deploy new features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JS file doesn't depend on any other JS. So We just placed that JS file into public directory.

**ADDED**
This is temporary solution as when asset precompiles, all the assets under public/asset would be wiped out and generated again